# show comments related to a facebook post inside app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

At the moment I have an app where I load in some news items that I get back from my `webservice`. This has at the moment no link with `facebook`. But now I want to get these `comments` that are related to that newsItem also in my app.

My question is now, I there a way that I can get the comments with the `Facebook IOS API`. Or should I just let my webservice handle it?

Comment: You can use Graph API for fetching the comments.